# Firebase data not working when refresh web browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux

Thanks for reading.

I have an issue with React, Redux and Firebase. I set the Firebase data at React store with Redux. Pass the data with mapStateToProps in the component. When I link in an item of firebase and refresh the web browser props of the data is undefined. I want when i refresh the browser stay the firebase data.

This is my component that show the data of firebase

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="content-container">
          <Header />
          <div className="square-top" />
          <div className="square" />
          <div className="middle-square" />

          <div className="box-content" style={{ marginTop: "20rem" }}>
            <img
              className="img-post"
              src={this.props.posts.image}
              alt=""
            />
            <h1>{this.props.posts.title}</h1>
            <p>{this.props.posts.description}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="box-content" style={{ paddingBottom: "400px" }}>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                this.props.history.push("/blog");
              }}
              className="btn-primary"
            >
              Volver
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts.find(post => post.slug === props.match.params.slug)
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostItemPage);
```

action Redux file

```
export const setPosts = posts => ({
  type: "SET_POSTS",
  posts
});

export const startSetPosts = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    return database
      .ref("posts")
      .once("value")
      .then(snapshot => {
        const posts = [];

        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          posts.push({
            id: childSnapshot.key,
            ...childSnapshot.val()
          });
        });

        dispatch(setPosts(posts));
      });
  };
};
```

and Store file

```
const composeEnhancers  = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      filters: filtersReducer,
      questions: questionsReducer,
      posts: postsReducer
    }),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );

  return store;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really provided enough information for anybody to provide you with a complete answer.

A few points to consider:

- What value does `props.match.params.slug` have? Are you passing this down from a parent component appropriately?
- Are you calling `startSetPosts()`, perhaps in your container component's `componentWillMount()` method?
- Have you tried logging the state that is in your store, at the point at which your container component is rendered? This will no doubt help you to debug where things are going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Charles sorry i'm starting with React and Firebase and my english is not good. I dispatch startSetPosts() in my App.js like this.

```
const jsx = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter />
  </Provider>
);

store.dispatch(startSetPosts());


ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById("app"));
```

About props.match.params.slug I pass the value from a parent component with mapStateToProps().

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  posts: selectCategory(state.posts, state.filters),
  filters: state.filters.category
});
```

I get the data from firebase with this structure:

```
posts{
  -LDCSkdmgh2F3FjmcoSp{
       description:
       image:
       slug:
       title: 
   }
}
```